# How to plot two lower triangular distance matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, distance

I have two lower triangular matrix one with pairwise geographic distance(m1) and another one with pairwise genetic distance(m2).

`m1` looks like this:

```
             SiteA  SiteB   SiteC       
     SiteA   0.00                           
     SiteB   51     0.00                                                            
     SiteC   207    61     0.00
```

`m2` looks like this:

```
pops 1,   2,    3,      
1,                                                                          
2,     0.0024                                                                       
3,     0.0207   0.0033
```

How can I plot these 2 matrices as X and Y graph in R?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
> # two matrices with some data:
> m1 <- matrix(seq(1,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
> m2 <- matrix(seq(11,19), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
> m1
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> m2
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   14   17
[2,]   12   15   18
[3,]   13   16   19
> 
> # plot lower triangular parts against each other:
> plot(m1[lower.tri(m1)], m2[lower.tri(m2)])
```

[image: X Y plot]